# How to split values from one cell to multiple cells using bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a file which looks like this:

```
1|2|3|4
1|2|3|4
1|2|3|4
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
```

For a easy understanding we can say that while some values are divides into different cells, there are other values that are stored in a *single* cell and separated by tabs (although I'm not really sure). What I want to do is to split these values into different cells so my output file should look like this:

```
1|2|3|4
1|2|3|4
1|2|3|4
1|2|3|4
1|2|3|4
1|2|3|4
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hello, what did you try? Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `tr`:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '|'
```

It translates each character using to sets. According to the manual page:

- **`-s`** (or `--squeeze-repeats`): replace each sequence of a repeated character that is listed  in the last specified SET, with a single occurrence of that character (i.e. used to remove duplicates of the character to replace)
- **`[:blank:]`**: all horizontal whitespaces (use `\t` instead if you're sure they are all tabs)

Comment: I've noticed that values are separated by many tabs. Do you have any idea of how to detect multiple tabs to add multiple pipes?

Comment: If you don't want to squeeze repeats, just remove the `-s` argument.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed with an "address":

```
sed '/|/!s/./|&/g;s/^|//'
```

- `/|/!` means "only run the following command on lines not containing `|`".
- `s/./|&/g` prepends `|` to each character on such lines.
- `s/^|//` removes `|` from the beginning of each line.

Or, use Perl:

```
perl -lne '$,="|"; print /\|/ ? $_ : split //'
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each
- `l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`
- `$,` is the variable that's normally empty. It specifies what string should be used to separate parameters to [print](http://p3rl.org/print).
- `condition ? then : else` is a ternary operator. If the condition (here `/\|/`, i.e. the lie contains `|`) is true, `$_` is printed, i.e. the line itself, otherwise, the line is [split](http://p3rl.org/split) into individual characters and they are printed separated by `$,`.

Or easier

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=.)(?=.)/|/g unless /\|/'
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing
- `(?<=.)` is a look-behind assertion and means "any character preceds"; `(?=.)` is a look-ahead assertion meaning "any character follows.
- unless the line already contains `|`, `|` is inserted between every two characters.

*Note:* You have changed the question, making all the answers invalid. Fixing the code is left as an exercise for the reader. It's usually better to ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your last comment. I'll take it into account next time and I really appreciate your effort!!!

Comment: I didn't figured out I was answering to the edited question. By the way I upvoted your answer as a well-written and detailled.